# Customizing table appearance in Matlab

Tags: matlab, customization

Say I have a table with several columns; these columns contain structured data, (either instances of classes or struct). Clearly when the table is displayed, it only shows as [1x1 struct] or something. I would like to instead display a particular field of that struct (in particular the ID field)  so I can have a quick look at the table without navigating it.

Is there a way to achieve this or shall I just create a function showTable() that does what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: That would mean overloading the command line output of MATLAB. Most likely possible only with very obscure java-related hacks.